# How do I get NethackCocoa to read my .nethackrc?

Tags: nethack

I wanted to play a graphical Nethack for a change, and I found NethackCocoa in the Mac App Store. What bothers me is that it ignores my `~/.nethackrc` - terminal Nethack works just fine with it. Snooping around in my system log I stumbled upon the following line:

```
sandboxd: ([56566]) NetHack(56566) deny file-read-data /Users/tourn/.nethackrc
```

So I figure the problem is Lion sandbox-related. Since I heard nobody else complaining though I think it's still a problem with my personal setup.

I'm on OSX 10.7.5, if that's any help.

Comment: Try installing the version that's not on the App Store. ([Download is here.](http://code.google.com/p/nethack-cocoa/)) It's not constrained by an App sandbox. Does that fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked around by installing the [version that's not on the App Store](http://code.google.com/p/nethack-cocoa/), thanks to @SevenSidedDie.

I'd still be interested in getting the App Store version working, just for the heck of it.

Answer (score 1):

The App Store version can find the config file if you store it inside the container here:

```
~/Library/Containers/net.hack.cocoa.NetHack/Data/.nethackrc
```

For convenience, you can link this into your home directory:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Containers/net.hack.cocoa.NetHack/Data/.nethackrc ~
```

It doesn’t look like the symbolic link will work the other way around, with the actual file in your home directory and a link inside the container. I suspect that the game does not have access to files outside the container.